# How do i update content of infowindow in loop with setInterval

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having problem in updating the infowindow content everytime my loop runs with the specified setInterval.Every 1 second the content of the infowindow will change each marker array...but I am having problem If I put the closure in the if statement. after 5 minuets the browser will crash because of adding the listener in every 1 second.what I want is to update only the content of each marker.how would I do that.?

Thank you in advance.

```
var map;
var marker;
var markerarray =[];

setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "vehiclecordinates.php",
    success: function(data){
      coordinates = data.latlng;
      vehiclename = data.vehiclename;
      heading      = data.heading;
      devname = data.vehiclename;
      thedate = data.trackdate;

      for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
        newcoordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i].split(",")[0],coordinates[i].split(",")[1]);
        if (markerarray[vehiclename[i]] && markerarray[vehiclename[i]].setPosition){

          markerarray[vehiclename[i]].icon.rotation = parseInt(heading[i]);
          markerarray[vehiclename[i]].setPosition(newcoordinate);

          var con = '<div style="font: 11px arial,tahoma,helvetica,sans-serif;">Vehicle Name:' + devname + '<br/>' +'Date='+thedate+'</div>';

        }else {
          marker =  new MarkerWithLabel({
            map:map,
            labelClass: "mylabels",
            labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0},
            labelContent: '<div>'+ vehiclename[i]+'</div>',
            icon:{
              path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale:.7,
            strokeColor: 'white',
            strokeWeight: .10,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            fillColor: '#404040',
            offset: '5%',
            rotation: parseInt(heading[i]),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 50)
            }
          });
          marker.setPosition(newcoordinate);
          markerarray[vehiclename[i]] = marker;
            var con = '<div style="font: 11px arial,tahoma,helvetica,sans-serif;">Vehicle Name:' + devname + '<br/>' +'Date='+thedate+'</div>';

        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', (function  (marker, con, infowindow) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(con);
            infowindow.open(map,  marker);
        };
        })( marker, con, infowindow));
        }




      }
    }
  });
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your anonymus `clickEventListener` function.

1. Then use javacript [code to remove click event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp).
2. If you use jquery to add the eventlistener then you can easily `unbind()` the function, or search for if it exists then don't add.
3. You can set a `bool`: `clickSet=true`, that you set after eventlistener once called.

Edit:

Code:

```
function  whatever(marker, con, infowindow) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(con);
            infowindow.open(map,  marker);
        };
};
var map;
var marker;
var markerarray =[];

setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "vehiclecordinates.php",
    success: function(data){
      coordinates = data.latlng;
      vehiclename = data.vehiclename;
      heading      = data.heading;
      devname = data.vehiclename;
      thedate = data.trackdate;

      for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
        newcoordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i].split(",")[0],coordinates[i].split(",")[1]);
        if (markerarray[vehiclename[i]] && markerarray[vehiclename[i]].setPosition){

          markerarray[vehiclename[i]].icon.rotation = parseInt(heading[i]);
          markerarray[vehiclename[i]].setPosition(newcoordinate);

          var con = '<div style="font: 11px arial,tahoma,helvetica,sans-serif;">Vehicle Name:' + devname + '<br/>' +'Date='+thedate+'</div>';

        }else {
          marker =  new MarkerWithLabel({
            map:map,
            labelClass: "mylabels",
            labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0},
            labelContent: '<div>'+ vehiclename[i]+'</div>',
            icon:{
              path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale:.7,
            strokeColor: 'white',
            strokeWeight: .10,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            fillColor: '#404040',
            offset: '5%',
            rotation: parseInt(heading[i]),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 50)
            }
          });
          marker.setPosition(newcoordinate);
          markerarray[vehiclename[i]] = marker;
            var con = '<div style="font: 11px arial,tahoma,helvetica,sans-serif;">Vehicle Name:' + devname + '<br/>' +'Date='+thedate+'</div>';

        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', whatever);
        }




      }
    }
  });
},1000);
```

Comment: how to put name on anonymous clickeventlistener ?

Comment: Before `var map;` inicialize it. `function somename(arugments) { stuffToDo(); }`. Then call it as `.addListener( marker, 'click',somename)`

Comment: ,what is inside in the stufftoddo() ?

Comment: ,why is it no parameter in whatever ? google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', whatever);

Comment: Parameters are given in the function. You can add them if you want.